# Firebase analytics UserDeletion.userDeletionRequest 403

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to delete Firebase analytics using **UserDeletion.userDeletionRequest** (that works fine for google analytics).  However I get

> "Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError User does not have sufficient
>   permissions for this User Deletion Request. [403]"

The service account has Editor Role, I also tried Owner. 
Also the Firebase admin SDK service account and a new service account on the console.cloud.google.com in my Firebase project. Will get me a 403.

What is the correct way to generate the service account for the Firebase analytics delete?

Answer (score 0):

You need to addd the [Firebase Admins SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to your server if you want to delete user data using a server API call.

To delete client data, follow [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/manage-iids#delete_an_instance_id) on adding code for Android and iOS apps by deleting the data from the respective instance ID.